# Add conditional counter: counter column based on value of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like this

```
id    id2      val
a     red      apple
a     red      orange
b     blue     fish
c     violet   beef
a     yellow   banana
a     black    pork
```

I want to create a counter based on the values of id and id2.

For example, id is the customer Id and id2 is the order Id and val is the item name in the order. I want to create a counter for the customer id and order id. So that's why the first 2 rows should have the same counter 1

I tried the cumcount but they will give me something likes this

```
id    id2      val      counter
a     red      apple    1
a     red      orange   2
b     blue     fish     1
c     violet   beef     1
a     yellow   banana   1
a     black    pork     1
```

I tried the cumcount

`df['counter'] = df.groupby(['id','id2']).cumcount() + 1`

but it is not what I want

I want a result table like this

```
id    id2      val      counter
a     red      apple    1
a     red      orange   1
b     blue     fish     1
c     violet   beef     1
a     yellow   banana   2
a     black    pork     3
```

Thank you,

Comment: I don't follow the expected output. Why should `yellow banana` be 2  but `violet beef` is only 1?

Comment: It's a counter within `id` for each unique value of `id2`.

Comment: @roganjosh sorry for being unclear. I just added some more info. for example. id is customer id and id2 is order id and val is the item id in the order. like a basket in your amazon order. I want to create a counter number of orders per customer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to count the unique values of pairs `(id, id2)`:

```
uniques = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id','id2']).groupby('id').cumcount()+1
df['counter'] = uniques.reindex(df.index).ffill().astype(int)
```

Comment: Hi anh, that's exactly what I need. Thank so much!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and [`pandas.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['counter'] = df.groupby(['id'])['id2'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]).add(1)

  id     id2     val  counter
0  a     red   apple        1
1  a     red  orange        1
2  b    blue    fish        1
3  c  violet    beef        1
4  a  yellow  banana        2
5  a   black    pork        3
```

Comment: can you explain how `pd.factorize(x)[0]` works. thanks

Comment: sure, it's a category label encoder... it encodes each unique category as an integer, starting from `0`, so in the first `id` "a", category "red" would be encoded to `0`, category "yellow" would be encoded to `1` and so forth. Hence the need to use `.add(1)` for the desired output. Since we're using it in a `groupby` the first observed category in each `id` will be encoded to `0`